# Is there a published feature matrix for Gazebo?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

While looking at "the competition", I noticed useful [Feature_Matrix](http://opensimulator.org/wiki/Feature_Matrix), and thought it might also be a good basis for metaphor to provide links to the functionality (and tutorials) for key Gazebo components.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/364/is-there-a-published-feature-matrix-for-gazebo?/) by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 319 on 2012-12-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Good idea. We have a more high-level feature matrix [here](http://gazebosim.org/user_guide/overview__features.html), but without links to tutorials.

---

Originally posted by [spaepcke](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/85/spaepcke/) with karma: 44 on 2012-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0